# Javascript: How to pause/stop currently playing audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I have the following code to play audio on my website. The problem is playing audio does not stop or pause to play a new one. All the files are playing together like crazy.

```
$().ready(function () {
    PlayMp3('sounds/file1.mp3');
    PlayMp3('sounds/file2.mp3');
    PlayMp3('sounds/file3.mp3');
    PlayMp3('sounds/file4.mp3');
});
    function PlayMp3(file) {
            var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
            var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
            var isiPod = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null;
            pauseAllAudio();

            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
                file = file.replace("mp3", "ogg");            
                $('#content').append('<audio src="' + file + '" controls preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none"></audio>');
            }
            else if (isiPad || isiPhone || isiPod) {           
                var snd = new Audio(file);
                snd.load();
                snd.play();            
            }
            else {
                $('#content').append('<embed height="0" width="0" src="' + file + '">');
            }


        }

        function pauseAllAudio() {
            $('video, audio').each(function () {
                $(this)[0].pause();
            });
            var allAudioEls = $('audio');
            allAudioEls.each(function () {
                var a = $(this).get(0);
                a.pause();
            });

            $('audio').remove();
            if (snd != undefined) {
                snd.pause();
            }
        }
```

This is not a duplicate question. I have tried all solutions from similar questions here and none of the solutions works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Praveen Kumar. Without him, I couldn't have found the problem to remove 'embed'. After adding `$('embed').remove();` to `function pauseAllAudio()`. It solves for all browsers but Firefox. That firefox doesn't like mp3 or `<embed>` tag. I had to do some more research to make it work for only that browser.

jPlayer looks great and it solves my problem. The solution is as follow.

```
 function PlayMp3(file) {
    $('embed').remove();
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
            file = file.replace("mp3", "ogg");
            $('#jquery_jplayer').jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            $('#jquery_jplayer').jPlayer("setMedia", { oga: file });
            $('#jquery_jplayer').jPlayer("play");
    }
    else {
        $('#content').append('<embed height="0" width="0" src="' + file + '">');
}
```

I had to give up on HTML 5 `<audio>` tag. :(

Answer (score 1):

Small change.

```
$('video, audio').each(function () {
    $(this).get(0).stop();
});
```

Say if it is working.

#### Update #1

Check if the following is working:

1. `$(this)[0].pause();`
2. `$(this).get(0).pause();`

Comment: It doesn't work. I even got script error now as "PM
Error: TypeError: $(this).get(0).stop is not a function
Source File:"

Comment: @JonasT Updated the answer. Check the two conditions! :)

Comment: I have tried both of your updated answers. None of them gives script error now but it doesn't pause either. :( I have updated my question with the site I am working on. You can try the quiz very quickly and will see the sounds are playing together horribly.

Comment: Okay. Will check and let you know.

Comment: @JonasT At any point of time I am getting the `$("video, audio").length` as `0`. Is there really those tags, or they are different?

Comment: I am getting $("video, audio").length "1" in Firefox and "0" in chrome.

Comment: Good point man. I was using <embed> for other browsers. I added  $('embed').remove(); and it is working in chrome. Need to fix to work in Firefox.

Comment: What is the issue with FF? What's happening?

Comment: $('video, audio').each(function () {
            $(this)[0].pause();
            alert($("video, audio").length);
            $(this).get(0).pause();
            $(this).remove();
            alert($("video, audio").length);
        }); First alert say "1" and second says "0". It doesn't pause playing. :(

Comment: Yes because Chrome is working with <embed> tag(not HMTL5 <audio>tag). When I remove <embed> tag from document it stops. Firefox cannot play ogg file with <embed> tag. That is crazy. Is there any work-around to get Firefox play audio with <embed> tag?

Comment: Nice. You found the issue. And your solution is in Wikipedia! `;)` Try to flick, else I will help you! `:)`

Comment: I think I have to use jplayer. I found one demo here. http://sethaldridge.com/demos/. It doesn't even use flash and it can even play mp3 format in forefox. When I go to jplayer website http://www.jplayer.org It uses flash and it doesn't have documentation for their old versions. :S

Comment: Are you using Flash now? `:O`

Comment: No flash is not an option. I have to find another solution to make it work on firefox. All other browsers work fine now.

Comment: No, actually I suggest you not to use flash, as no Apple product supports it! :(

Comment: mate, jplayer works on apple products too. It works on android tablets and everything. I will stick it for any audio from now on.